# Video capture device: any chance of getting raw data?

Tags: linux, drivers, video, hdmi

I have a HDMI capture device called Live Gamer Portable (AverMedia C875 USB - 07ca:0875), and it has drivers for Windows and Mac, but not for Linux. As it has Mac support, is it possible to access raw data from this device under Linux?

This is what appears in `dmesg` when the device is connected in PC Mode:

```
usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
usb 3-3: device not accepting address 3, error -71
usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=07ca, idProduct=0875
usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-3: Product: Aver_C875_USB
usb 3-3: Manufacturer: AVerMedia Tech. Inc.
usb 3-3: SerialNumber: ************
usb 3-3: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 2 microframes, ep desc says 3 microframes
usb 3-3: ep 0x4 - rounding interval to 2 microframes, ep desc says 3 microframes
usb 3-3: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 2 microframes, ep desc says 3 microframes
```

And, for more info, this is what appears in `lsusb -v` for this device:
http://pastebin.com/B4Bhriw4

I have a bit of hope for this because AverMedia is kinda Linux-friendly with other devices they have: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia

I didn't know the best place to post this kind of request, as AverMedia doesn't have a forum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get raw video using different library like  v4l2.

For more help [v4l2 help](http://lwn.net/Articles/203924/).

Comment: Thanks, gonna take a look. I'm not a drive developer though...

Answer (score 0):

Use the software kino. Start it, then press capture -> capture.